# Remove 'empty' enum value from enum list (dropdown) on Swagger UI

Tags: enums, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

Trying to get rid of the 'empty' value from the enum list on Swagger UI.

[image: Swagger empty value]

My field `options` is a list of enums which null is not a part of it. My OpenApi3 specification is as below:

```
"description": "number of options", 
"explode": true, 
"in": "query", 
"name": "options", 
"required": false, 
"schema": {
  "items": {
    "enum": [
      1, 
      2, 
      3
    ], 
    "type": "string"
  }, 
  "type": "array"
}, 
"style": "form"
```

I seem to make it disappear if I make the field `required`:

[image]

But I don't want this.
The field should be either nullable or be part of one of the enum values.
The reason is that, if the 'empty' value is selected, the request goes like

```
 http://localhost?options=&...
```

This brings undesirable results since '' (empty string) is not part of the enum.

Comment: Did you solve this? I am running into the same issue

Comment: Nope, still have that ```--``` lingering there

Comment: I think this [issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5176) is related to the question